# Enterprise Architect - simple UI Tab Control

Tags: user-interface, uml, tabcontrol, enterprise-architect

Is it possible to change number of tabs and tabs name in simple UI Tab Control? How to do it? (user interface diagram)

I'm using EA 11.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. `Tab 1 | Tab 2 | Tab 3` is part of the element's image and you can't change them. There is a workaround which works visually, but won't help if you're looking to generate code out of your models.

1. Create a Text element (in the Common toolbox), and give it the name of your GUI's first tab.
2. Set a different default fill and text color for the Text element (Right-click and select Appearence - Default Appearance).
3. Pick the Fill and Border Color for the Text element that best matches the Tab Control's foreground, either in the diagram toolbar or the Text element's context menu.
4. Move and resize the Text element to cover `Tab 1`.
5. Repeat as necessary for the other tabs, using the appropriate color.

The Text elements are local to the diagram they're in and are not shown in the project browser (they are diagram objects but not proper model elements), but they move with the Tab Control so it works visually.

By making several copies of the Tab Control and varying which Text element has the foreground color, you can use this technique to show the different panes.

Answer (score 0):

You can change number of tabs and selected tab this way (at least in EA 13):

1. Open Properties of the Tab Control;
2. In "General" select "Wireframing" tab. You'll see "Tabs" property with a value "Tab1";
3. Select this "Tabs" property and click on "Notes" menu. An editor appears;
4. In this editor you can change number of names of tabs;
5. Close editor and for "Tabs" property choose selected Tab;
   [image: Changing tabs in Sparx EA wireframing]